# Store return value from async function imported from another file as a variable that can be referenced elseware

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

I'm working with the Azure rest api. The first task when calling the Azure Rest API is you need to get your access/bearer token.

What I've done is I have a file called utils.js with the following async function.

utils.js

```
async function get_bearer_token(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret) {
    console.log('Getting Bearer Token');
    let token_url = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenant_id}/oauth2/token`;
    let data = {
        'resource': 'https://management.core.windows.net',
        'client_id': client_id,
        'client_secret': client_secret,
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
    };
    let config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    };

    let bearer_token;
    await axios.post(token_url, qs.stringify(data), config).then(({data}) => {
        bearer_token = data.access_token});
    return bearer_token;
};
```

This works and returns the bearer_token as one would expect. My issue, being brand new to JS and using this as a training exercise, is that I've got my main code file and i've imported this function into that file and attempting to get back the bearer token.

I only ever end up with the pending promise. I'm trying to do something such as:

```
let bearer_token;
get_bearer_token(process.env.TENANT_ID, process.env.CLIENT_ID, process.env.CLIENT_SECRET).then(data => {bearer_token = data});
console.log(bearer_token);
```

I will need this bearer token numerous times to complete my other tasks. This above code returns a pending promise from the function call but undefined when I try to log the variable after that. I can make this all work, but I end up in callback hell and I'm positive there has to be a better way, I just don't see it.

How can I set the return value of an async function in one file to a variable in another file where i've actually called this async function?

Comment: You've got to `await` the call, or else use a `.then()` callback. `async` function calls always result in a promise.

Comment: You can't - you're trying to crossover async and sync, defeating the purpose of its duality. You can either make all of your code synchronous, or all of it asynchronous. For example, @Pointy's answer makes the whole thing asynchronous.

Comment: @Endothermic_Dragon so long as there's an Axios method in the middle of getting the desired value, it's going to have to be asynchronous.

Comment: @Pointy, I realize that now. I didn't look at the code fully, I went straight to the question. I usually do this so I can look for the problem as I read the rest again from the beginning.

Comment: So is it just impossible to have a constant variable set from the return of an async function to be reused without nesting everything inside the previous functions .then() block?